# Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter' to type 'iTextSharp.tool.xml.IElementHandler'

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I am trying to write HTML string to a newly created PDF but I am getting the following error:
**Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter' to type 'iTextSharp.tool.xml.IElementHandler'.**

**CODE:**

```
Dim doc As text.Document
Dim output As New MemoryStream
doc = New text.Document(text.PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 50, 50)
Dim fileName As String = "~/Invoices/" + invoiceNumber + ".pdf"

Dim writer As text.pdf.PdfWriter = text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(Server.MapPath(fileName), FileMode.Create))

doc.AddTitle("PPN Rebate Invoice")
doc.AddAuthor("PPN")
doc.Open()

Dim reader As TextReader = New StringReader(html)

XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, reader)
```

This is my first time using iTextSharp.dll not sure what I am missing or doing wrong

Comment: Did you try one of the other overloads, maybe `XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, reader)`?

Comment: It is trying to convert doc to Stream and reader to Encoding:
Value of type 'iTextSharp.text.Document' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.Stream'
Value of type 'System.IO.TextReader' cannot be converted to 'System.Text.Encoding'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example - paste into a new console application to try out.  I added iTextSharp and iTextSharp XML Worker packages from NuGet.  Note the different overload of `ParseXHtml` that is being used.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.tool.xml

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim fileName As String = "C:\Dev\SO.pdf"
        Using doc = New Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 50, 50)
            Using writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
                doc.Open()
                doc.AddTitle("PPN Rebate Invoice")
                doc.AddAuthor("PPN")
                Dim html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><p>This is a test.</p></body></html>"
                Using reader As TextReader = New StringReader(html)
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, reader)
                End Using
                doc.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```